# How to get Metadata / versions for sub-properties / TwinCollection?

Tags: kotlin, azure-iot-sdk

I´m using the Azure IoT SDK for Java DeviceTwin functionality. On calling `startDeviceTwin()`, I receive the reported and desired properties once in the `TwinPropertyCallBack`.

However, inside of the `Property` sent, I can only get the `version` of the 'root node', not for the sub-properties or `TwinCollection`s (they are all `null`). On Azure Portal, I can clearly see that all of them have their own versions in the metadata section of the JSON. Example:

```
...
  "properties": {
    "desired": {
      "Broadcast": {
        "0": {
          "Scene": 2,
          "Brightness": 13
        }
      },
      "$metadata": {
        "$lastUpdated": "2020-12-01T07:53:53.0372127Z",
        "$lastUpdatedVersion": 17,
        "Broadcast": {
          "0": {
            "$lastUpdated": "2020-12-01T07:53:53.0372127Z",
            "$lastUpdatedVersion": 17,
            "Scene": {
              "$lastUpdated": "2020-12-01T07:53:53.0372127Z",
              "$lastUpdatedVersion": 17
            },
            "Brightness": {
              "$lastUpdated": "2020-12-01T07:28:08.5730028Z",
              "$lastUpdatedVersion": 15
            }
          },
          "$lastUpdated": "2020-12-01T07:53:53.0372127Z",
          "$lastUpdatedVersion": 17
        }
      },
      "$version": 17
    },
...
```

How can I receive these versions for the nested `TwinCollection`s? Is it some configuration or is it just not supported currently?

In the above example, I want to prevent re-processing of the Brightness value, as my local state is already at 'Version 15'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related Github issue posted at:[Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/issues/1011#issuecomment-737864414)

Below is the response from MicrosoftTeam.

> The service does not send that metadata to devices by design. It is
> only available to service clients who request for a device's twin. In
> general, you will need to rely on the overall version of the document
> for concurrency protection.

Please comment below if you need further help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#back-end-operations) you should get the lastUpdatedVersion for each and every property. I'm able to get the whole metaData object including the lastUpdatedVersion in NodeJS, so similar functionality should work in Java too.